# multivariable calculus charge density question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

The sphere given by $x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 4$ is submerged in an electric field with charge density given by $f(x, y, z) = x^{2} + y^{2}$. Find the total amount of electric charge on this surface.

I am stuck on what integral formula to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve this by integrating over the surface of the sphere in spherical coordinates
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=4 \rightarrow r=2$$
$$f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2 \rightarrow f(\theta,\phi)=sin^2(\theta)$$
$$dA = r^2sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi$$
$$\iint_{S(A)}sin^2(\theta)dA=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}4sin^3(\theta)d\theta d\phi=
\frac{32\pi}{3}$$